# Java main class not found error

Tags: java, ubuntu

I am running a jar on ubuntu and it works very well but after some time,the program fails to start and i get this error when i try running the jar from the terminal.

```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> jar-CafePilot_Server Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> jar-CafePilot_Server  at
> java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)    at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)    at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)     at
> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)     at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) Could not find
> the main class: jar-CafePilot_Server.  Program will exit.
```

Why am i getting this error.

Comment: The CafePilot_Server class file probably does not have the extension .class

Comment: This is the second its happening.It runs okay for some days then it don't start.My guess is that something is changing the classpath on ubuntu.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is `java -jar CafePilot_Server.jar`, not `java jar-CafePilot_Server`.

Answer (score 1):

You should check you CLASSPATH.

try this answer: [linuxquestions](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/installing-cafe-pilot-java-error-604098/)